# Latest Volley Version haven't setShouldCache method?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I need to do a petition with Volley, nowadays the version of volley 1.0.9 doesn't have the method request.setShouldCache(false); to cancel the cache. I've tried with volley+ (a fork of volley) but it doesn't have it too.

What I can do to cancel the cache? I need to cancel it in order to make a login petition each time.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions the method disappear, now we can use:

```
volley_queue.getCache().clear();
```

To clear the cache.